# How to prove Equivalence

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to show that

$1\cdot (A \cup B) \cap C = (A\cap C) \cup (B\cap C)$

$2\cdot (A\cap B) \cup C = (A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C)$

How can I show that the left hand side is equal to right hand side ? I feel like I have to use associativity or distributivity but I'm not sure how to make proof exactly.

Thank you.

Comment: You're proving distributivity, so you can't use that. You need to show that any element in the lefthand side is contained in the righthand side, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to just prove $1)$, and hopefully that will give you an idea for $2)$.

We show that $ (A \cup B) \cap C \subseteq(A\cap C) \cup (B\cap C)$ and vice versa. Suppose $x\in (A \cup B) \cap C $. Then $x\in C$ and $x\in A\cup B$. WLOG, suppose $x\in A$. Then clearly $x\in A\cap C$, and we're done. The same follows for $x\in B$.

We now show $(A \cup B) \cap C \supseteq (A\cap C) \cup (B\cap C)$. Suppose $x\in(A\cap C) \cup (B\cap C)$. Then $x\in A\cap C$ or $x\in B\cap C$. WLOG, suppose the former holds. Then $x\in A$ and $x\in C$. Thus, $x\in A\cup B$, and we're done. The case where the latter holds is almost exactly the same.

Can you follow my logic to show 2)?

Comment: First of all thank you for a clean explanation. I assume that(if I'm not wrong) you are trying to show that for each case, x is element of a property. Then at the end you are able to show x is element of the property that we need to prove. Let me try for the second part.

Answer (score 0):

$$ (A \cap B) \cup C = ( A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C)
$$

Suppose that, $$ x \in (A \cap B) \cup C $$

Then, $$ x \in A \cap B $$ or $$ x \in C $$ // I assume that the reason why we have a difference in this step as ( AND - OR) because there exist a Union rather than an Intersection.

Therefore, $$ x \in A$$

And we can do the almost same(copy the steps) for $$ x \in B$$

Now we have to show that $$ (A \cap B) \cup C = ( A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C)
$$

Suppose $$ x \in (A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C)$$

Then,$$ x \in (A \cup C) $$ and $$ x \in (B \cup C)$$

So,
$$ x \in A $$ or $$ x \in C $$

Thus,
$$ x \in (A \cap B)$$

Did I got right ?

Comment: You're on the right track, but not quite there. First, it looks like you're assuming what you're trying to prove by saying that the two sides are equal. Instead, say that you want to show they are subsets of one another.

Comment: Yes, right i got the logic !

Thanks for everything.